# Is link pointing to this page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For my website's navigation I want to give all the links to the current page a color.
How do I find which links are pointing to the current page?
A link's `href` is like "../index.php" but the current page is http://mysite.myserver.com/index.php.

This is my current approach, which doesn't want to work:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(str) { return ( this.match(str + "$") == str ); }
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) { return ( this.match("^" + str) == str ) }
String.prototype.trim = function(sec)
{
    var res = this;

    while (res.startWith(sec))
    {
        res = res.substr(sec.length);
    }

    while (res.endsWith(sec))
    {
        res = res.substr(0, res.length - sec.length);
    }

    return res;
}
```

And, when the document is ready:

```
$("a").each(
    function (i)
    {
        if (window.location.pathname.endsWith($(this).attr("href").trim(".")))
        {
            $(this).addClass("thispage");
        }
    }
);
```

And yes, I know this might color the home link (../index.php - because all pages end with that!). That's why I need a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a[href]").filter(function() {
    return window.location.pathname === this.pathname;
}).addClass("thispage");
```

Regarding your comment, if the window.location is a directory, you can create a string that ends with `index.php`.

```
var win = window.location.pathname; 
if( win.slice(-1) === '/' ) { 
    win += 'index.php'; 
} 
$("a[href]").filter(function() {
    return win === this.pathname;
}).addClass("thispage");
```

Comment: Wait, I need some help... If, for example, the link is "../index.php" and the current URL is "http://mysite.myserver.com/", it will fail, even if the web pages are actually the same!

Comment: @Vercas: Just test to see if the `window.location.pathname` ends with `/`, and if so concatenate `index.php`. Something like `var win = window.location.pathname; if( win.slice(-1) == '/' ) { win += 'index.php'; } return win === this.pathname;` I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Does this have to be done in javascript? It seems it would be easier to set the class in your page generation code.

Comment: I am going to have lots of pages, and, I might do changes to the header in the future. It would be a pain in the arse to change all the tags manually when copying and pasting the HTML, right?

Comment: Shouldn't be, if you plan ahead. And you shouldn't be copying and pasting much. You should instead use the html generation and composition mechanisms provided by your template engine of choice.

Comment: Template engine? What is that?

Comment: @pt2ph8 @ykaganovich Does anyone care to explain me more?

Comment: You use a template engine to build your website using web templates, which allow you to easily inject server-side constructs into your HTML. In PHP, http://www.smarty.net/ is a popular template engine. If you want to use a really simple basic one http://www.massassi.com/php/articles/template_engines/ works well. And if you use a web application framework, it probably has a built-in support for some default one, like this: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html

Comment: Forget them. I've templated my own pages now, with a common header and now I've made a loop to detect the correct path to the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try the a:visited class. This allows you to specify the color of a visited  tag.
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes

Comment: I want only THE CURRENT PAGE colored, not all the visited pages!